# rfs6000 wireless switch removing Vlans

Tags: switch, wireless

We were wondering if there was a command to remove the vlans on an rfs6000 switch?
We have tried factory resting the switch with the Username: restore but this keeps the Vlans. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: that's about cisco machine vlan, maybe it's a standard: IDs 1 and 1002 to 1005 are automatically created and cannot be removed. (CNNA certification course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### **3.1.21 erase**
>
> *Privileged Exec Mode Commands*
>   Erases a device’s (wireless controller, access point, and service platform) file system. Erases the content of the specified storage device. Also erases the startup configuration to restore the device to its default.

[RFS6000 Support](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Wireless+Networks/Wireless+LAN/Unified+Access+Platforms/RFS6000_RF_Switch_US-EN) >>> [Motorola Solutions WiNG 5.5.5 CLI Reference Guide](https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/manuals/MN001394A01.pdf)[pdf], (p.3-57)

---

`erase startup-config` should do it. That should put it back to "factory fresh".